# Android, fragment state after FragmentTransaction.add

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments,

fragmentA in foreground

now I show fragmentB with `FragmentTransaction.add(id, Fagment)`, (not `.replace`) so the fragmentA is still alive, with fragmentB on top of it,

now I use `back` button, here the fragmentB is destroyed, leaving fragmentA visible,

at this moment, how would I know that fragmentA has returned to the "foreground", ie `onResume`,

note that `onResume` is not called, due to `FragmentTransaction.add(id, Fagment)`, in other words, fragmentA doesn't go `onPause` when fragmentB is shown

thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to know when fragment A becomes visible again, you can first hide it in the fragment transaction that creates fragment B:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(id, fragmentB).hide(fragmentA).addToBackStack(null);
```

Then in Fragment A, override onHiddenChanged:

```
@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
    // Handle visibility changed. Note this method is called only when the state is changed.
}
```

When the back button is pressed, the fragment transaction will be reversed and the fragment's state will be changed to visible. One thing you have to watch out for: I've noticed that the hidden state isn't preserved between activity rotation so you'd have to perform your own bookkeeping in onSaveInstanceState. I do something similar to what you're asking since in my case the fragment views are expensive to recreate.

Before doing this though, you might want to consider handling your fragments another way, like with .replace() instead of .add(). If your fragment is completely hidden by the new fragment, then maybe you don't need to keep it around, and you can let the fragment manager bring it back once the user hits the back button. That way, you can just use the normal lifecycle functions like onPause and onResume.

Comment: I agree with you, if I use .replace instead of .add it will work using onPause and onResume, but I'm only using that because of the animation (and because I have only 3 very light fragments), I'm using a slide animation from the left that makes the second view cover the first, without making the first view to move, 

any way, I'll try it with the .hide method, thanks !!

Comment: +1 Thanks for the remark about the hidden state not being preserved across config changes! This looks like a bug :/ ? Can't imagine it's meant to work this way, since it really screws up things. On another note: afaik if you need to communicate with a previous fragment, using replace is not an option - at least that's what I have heard. Provided you need the original fragment, if you can live with a re-creation of it, I guess it'd be ok.